# BFC groups characterization

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am studying this theorem from Robinson's "A Course in the Theory of Groups", but I am having trouble with some steps in the proof. A BFC-group is a group for which there exists a positive integer $d$ such that no element of the group has more than $d$ conjugates.

The statement of the theorem is: A group $G$ is a BFC-group if and only if the commutator subgroup $G'$ is finite.

I have problems with the left-to-right implication: I will report the proof on the book and my doubts in brackets (...).

Proof: Let $G$ be a BFC-group, $d$ the maximum number of elements in the conjugacy class, $a$ that one element with exactly $d$ conjugates in $G$. Thus $|G: C_{G}(a)|= d$.

Choose a right transversal $t_{1}, ...t_{d}$ to $C_{G}(a)$ and define $C$ to be the intersection of the centralizers of $C_{G}(t_{i})$, $i= 1..d$.

Since $|G:C|$ is finite (first problem: why is it finite? Does it have to do with the indexes of $C_{G}(t_{i})$ maybe being finite as well?), there is a finite right transversal $\left\{s_1, ...s_k\right\}$ to $C$ in $G$. Now, consider $N = \langle a, s_1, ... s_k \rangle^G$, the normal closure of $\langle a, s_1, ... s_k \rangle$. This is finitely generated and an FC group (why is it an FC- group?

Is it sufficient to check this on the generators? If so, I'm ok with $a$, but I don't know how to prove that $s_1, ... , s_k$ have finite conjugacy class).

So $Z(N)$ has finite index and its elements of finite order in $N$ form a finite subgroup. Since $G'$ is a torsion group, it is sufficient to prove that $G' \leq N$.

It is then easily proven that $C' \leq N$. But $G= NC$ (why?) and this implies that $G' \leq NC' \leq N$ (why?).

Comment: I've paragraphed your question. Is this in line with what you intended?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: There are a few too many questions here, but here are a couple of comments. The intersection of a finite collection of subgroups of finite index of $G$ has finit eindex in $G$. That answers the first question. Then any subgroup of a BFC-group is itself a BFC-group (isn't that clear?).

Comment: @DerekHolt About my first question: my problem is in understanding why the centralizers $C_{G}(t_{i})$ have finite index, I only know that $C_{G}(a)$ has index $d$.

Comment: @DerekHolt About my second question: yes, I totally missed it, thank you.

Comment: But we are assuming that all conjugacy classes of $G$   have size at most $d$, so the centralizers of all elements have index at most $d$ in $G$.

Comment: Right, thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, I don't believe that $N$ necessarily has finite index in $G$ -in fact  $N$ could be finite. $G = NC$ follows from $t_1,\ldots,t_n \in N$, and in your final "why" it is not clear which of the inequalities you are asking about.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I meant that the centre $Z(N)$ has finite index, I'll edit that. I'm not sure about the $G' \leq NC'$.

Comment: $[G,G] = [NC,NC] \le [N,N][N,C][C,C] \le NC'$.

Comment: Thank you very much.